# In the curve building process, why do we need funding curve and projected curve and what are they exactly in current industry?

Tags: yield-curve, bootstrapping, curve-fitting, multicurve

I am a newbie to fixed income quant side and I am trying to understand in the **curve building process**, why do we need **funding curve** and **projected curve** and what are they exactly in current industry?

Could someone please give me some simple introduction about the curve building procedure ?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Projection and Discounting Curves](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/49873/projection-and-discounting-curves) "Funding" is synonymous with "discouting" curve. "Projection" is synonymous with "coupon" curve.

Comment: @DimitriVulis This is very helpful and that is what i am asking, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're very welcome, and please say hello to Ventzi if you interact with him.

Comment: @DimitriVulis It is a small world! I will when I get a chance :)